# Fetching multiple documents at the same time

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch multiple documents but I'm unable to do it. I wanted to fetch multiple documents containing my search criteria.

Here's what I tried.

```
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await db
              .collection('MyCollection')
              .where('FldName', 'in', ['123', '345', '111']).get();
```

Error on the syntax which is pointing in the `'in'`:

`Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found.`

Here's what my firebase looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `whereIn` like this:

```
.where('FldName', whereIn: ['123', '345', '111']).get();
```

Not, `in` as a `String`.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested, but still saying  too many positional arguments

Comment: I tried to search the whereIn and found this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any
but still unable to make it work

Comment: The documentation you've linked to isn't for flutter. Here are the docs for [flutter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/).

Comment: There was a type on the answer, after `whereIn` there should be a `:` not a comma.

Comment: I tried to check the output: `Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'` How will I see the data?

Comment: I saw it now. I used `.docs` and loop it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The where query might be incorrect, try using this one that I got from the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying).

```
.where('FldName', arrayContainsAny: ['123', '345', '111'])
```

Comment: This actually don't have syntax error. But my problem here is what if the field has 1234. It seems it will be captured as well?

Comment: No it '1234' won't match the query. Only documents that have '123' or '345' or '111' will be matched.

Comment: Ohh okay. Let me try.

Comment: If it worked, just press the tick button, or if you have any more doubts let me know in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure why but `arrayContainsAny` won't fetch any. But `whereIn` works. Anyway, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.